# Joomla 1.5: $this->countModules returns 1 for Jumi module even when empty

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, jumi

Working on a site in Joomla 1.5! Typically when testing if a module position is empty in Joomla! I'd do something like this:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('position')): ?>
    BEFORE
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position" style="xhtml" />
    AFTER
<?php endif; ?>
```

But in my case I have a [jumi module](http://2glux.com/projects/jumi) that references external source of code.
[image: jumi module that references external source of code]

In some situations it will be blank, which in that case, I don't want the BEFORE and AFTER bits showing either. But whenever I try running the above code, the before and after sections show up, because 
$this->countModules() returns 1 instead of 0.

I have "Hide if empty" set to "Yes" for the module, but that doesn't seem to help.
[image: hide if empty]

I've even tried setting a return false; on the external source code but that doesn't seem to help either.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hide if empty` cannot hide the `BEFORE and AFTER` because it's in the count condition.And `BEFORE and AFTER`  will only hide if no module is enabled for that position. So to hide these you'll have to put this content inside your module.And check the if empty condition.
Let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: That misses the point though.  Other modules would just not show up, so the count would return 0 instead of 1, and would not show the BEFORE and AFTER sections.

Comment: No I think you're wrong there. The count counts modules assigned to that position. As long as the module is published and enabled then `$this->countModules('position')` will have a value of 1 (or more depending on how many modules are assigned to this position)